# How can I disable rvm's interactive help (pager?) i.e. more / less a la `man`?

Tags: command-line, ruby, rvm

I recently upgraded from `rbenv` to the newest version of `rvm`. If I type a command such as:

```
rvm help
```

Then it gives me the same sort of paging interface I would get with `man rvm` - but I just want it to print out the help without allow me to search or scroll up and down, and having to press `q` to quit.

Granted I can do something like:

```
rvm help | cat
```

But that seems unnecessary. From Stack Overflow, [git provides a way to disable the pager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183900/how-do-i-prevent-git-diff-from-using-a-pager), does `rvm` also provide this? Hopefully there is something I can add to an `.rvm` config file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be to use alias:

```
alias rvm='PAGER=cat rvm'
```

I'm not sure if it can be done with `.rvm`.

Comment: Thanks! This was a great idea! With `zsh`, since `rvm` was already an alias, which is set from `~/.rvm/scripts/cl`, I just added the `PAGER=cat` to the beginning of the `rvm()` function.